# How to interpret the expression "pour ce qui nous occupe"

Tags: sens, expressions

> C'est tombé à point nommé **pour ce qui nous occupe**.
>
> = for us / as far as we are concerned ???

The context helped me make an educated guess, but how do you use this expression in other examples? I wonder if this is a variant of "pour ce qui est de ..."?

Comment: Linguee has a number of examples and translations: http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/qui+nous+occupe.html

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Hi. Although the "occuper" in those examples has the same meaning, it's a little bit different, as none of them has "pour"! Which is exactly what I'm curious about here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On pourrait imaginer des contextes où *pour ce qui nous occupe* aurait le même sens que *en ce qui nous concerne*, mais il me semble que dans la plupart des cas ces deux expressions ont des sens différents. Donc ces expressions sont à considérer uniquement en contextes.

**Pour ce qui nous occupe** désigne une affaire sur laquelle on travaille ou on réfléchit.

Exemples en contexte :

- [Première phrase d'un exposé](https://www.senat.fr/leg/ppl12-064.html) sur une proposition de loi visant à instituer un délit de harcèlement religieux :

  > Le prosélytisme désigne l'attitude de ceux qui cherchent à rallier des personnes à une doctrine. Il vise, à terme, la conversion de l'autre et pour ce qui nous occupe<sup>1</sup>, sa conversion religieuse.

  → « pour ce qui nous occupe » désigne l'objet de l'exposé qui est en discussion : le fait religieux.
- Dans [un article](http://www.20minutes.fr/sport/1640751-20150626-coupe-monde-buteuse-entraineure-bon-sang-comment-faut-appeler-joueuses-foot) qui se pose la question de savoir comment faut-il appeler les joueuses de foot :

  > Pour ce qui nous occupe ici<sup>2</sup>, on apprend que « la forme féminine se termine par – euse lorsque le nom correspond à un verbe en rapport sémantique direct de métiers, titres, grades et fonctions », ce qui est le cas d’entraîneur/euse, par ailleurs cité en exemple.

  → « pour ce qui nous occupe »  désigne le sujet de l'article, à savoir la féminisation des noms.

On emploie en **en ce qui me/nous concerne** quand on donne son opinion sur quelque chose, et pas forcément une affaire dont on s'occupe, par exemples :

- > En ce qui me concerne<sup>3</sup>, j'en vois le signe dans la difficulté que j'éprouve à faire progresser la négociation... Je ne serais pas hostile en ce qui me concerne... ([*Documents diplomatiques français*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=neB9iAAtJO4C&pg=PA571&lpg=PA571&dq=sens%20%22en%20ce%20qui%20me%20concerne%22&source=bl&ots=usm_vyuOii&sig=5LxqnnKglbGwz5hBofmtlGvd7as&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkqZCStaTVAhXRmLQKHSRhB3c4ChDoAQgxMAQ#v=onepage&q=sens%20%22en%20ce%20qui%20me%20concerne%22&f=false), vol. 2, Ministère des affaires étrangères - 2008)

  > En ce qui nous concerne<sup>4</sup>, l'importance de la physiologie moderne est double. (*[*Une histoire de la modernité sonore*, Jonathan STERNE, 2015](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eaJ4CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT54&lpg=PT54&dq=sens%20%22en%20ce%20qui%20nous%20concerne%22&source=bl&ots=bhTHgLElmr&sig=_09v82aISxNkCU_hNgR2LZY6PV0&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik_cjutaTVAhUNU1AKHcWyBpgQ6AEIUjAJ#v=onepage&q=sens%20%22en%20ce%20qui%20nous%20concerne%22&f=false))*

Parfois *en ce qui nous concerne* peut avoir le sens de *pour ce qui nous occupe*, comme dans cet exemple :

- > En ce qui nous concerne ici, cela revient en premier lieu à conduire des entretiens avec des agriculteurs, à enregistrer ces entretiens pour les transcrire.. ( [Le sens des pratiques: Conceptions d'agriculteurs et modèles d'agronomes](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_NIiCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=sens%20%22en%20ce%20qui%20nous%20concerne%22&source=bl&ots=lpsmD4vcjg&sig=mUehkQBzizeMQsZGrOGVb1ubB64&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik_cjutaTVAhUNU1AKHcWyBpgQ6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=sens%20%22en%20ce%20qui%20nous%20concerne%22&f=false), Jean-Pierre Darré, Anne Mathieu, Jacques Lasseur - 2004)

En ce qui me concerne, la phrase :

> C'est tombé à point nommé pour ce qui nous occupe.

n'exprime pas une opinion mais fait référence à une chose sur laquelle on travaille.

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>about what  we are dealing with here (about our subject matter)</sub> 
<sup>2</sup>  <sub>concerning this matter</sub>
<sup>3</sup>  <sub>as far as I am concerned</sub>
<sup>4</sup>  <sub>as far as we are concerned</sub>

Comment: Now I realise that "pour une **tâche/affaire** qui nous occupe" helps to make the expression clearer. ;) Or "pour une **tâche/affaire** dont nous nous occupons".

Comment: An enlightening explanation of a fine distinction!